# Wifi connects disconnects on android

Tags: wi-fi, networking, stock-android, motorola

I have android device with stock android(moto edge 20). Whenever the wifi signal(router) are weak the wifi disconnects. This problem is frequent when my device is connect to a Bluetooth device. This problem mostly occurs when wifi signal is weak and I am doing some internet heavy task, like watching 1080p YouTube video, as the buffering starts the wifi disconnects. I have tried this on many device and the problem is only coming with phones with stock android and not with phones which have some other custom skin.

Stock Android devices I have test this issue with are,

- Moto Edge 20
- Moto One Fusion Plus
- Asus Max Pro M1
- Xiaomi Mi M1

With all these devices I am facing the same issue. I have also tried this with Realme Narzo 30 5g and Samsung M51 and for both of these devices there is no such problem.

Can anybody give a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you refer to a personal mobile hotspot rather than a router.

You could try Settings > Connections > Mobile Hotspot> changing the AP band to 5.0Ghz.

Comment: No, I am referring to a router.

Comment: The signal is weak from the start. But since it's only these set of phones. I suggest changing the setting of the router to a lower AP band and try it. If it doesn't work, try a higher band

Comment: The setting comes with the IP address of the router itself not the ISP. I had similar problems with the Ghz, some phones tend to only accommodate lower band

Comment: Yes I have tried, no help.

Comment: Both 2.4Ghz and 5.0Ghz

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed this problem with many people who are using stock android and they all have confirmed.

Comment: Okay, it seems to be an issue with it being a stock android, some features are lacking. I suggest a move to custom rom if you don't mind; if not, a little tweaking from bootloader but might involve changing your network settings and a possible brick.